When MRR used in mysql Queries
We are using MySQL 8.0.35, Here we are facing some slow queries in our production, When we checked the explain plan In all slow queries there is an hint "Using MRR".
So when we execute the same query separately in terminal, Sometimes "Using MRR" is not used and the query executes faster and sometimes "Using MRR" is used and slowed.
So taken Optimizer trace for both scenarios, From there is no clue how MRR optimization is used in the query.
Can someone explain how MRR(Multi Range Read) Optimization is used in an Query with some examples.
NOTE : Mysql MRR Optimization
I have read the above MRR doc In that I can understand how the MRR working and how the optimization works, But I can't understand how and when this optimisation is applied to the query.

Have you read this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mrr-optimization.html  If so, please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you want to know.

Hi @O.Jones Thanks for an reply, I have read the doc In that I can understand how the MRR working and how the optimization works, But I can't understand how this optimisation is applied to the query.
I will update question as well.

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
for analysis of mrr-optimization factors to provide possible suggestions.

Please also post the complete QUERY (using MRR and NOT using MRR, if possible)  along with EXPLAIN SELECT ...... so we can see what the optimizer is doing today.  We will also NEED TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (each table used); for analysis.
